# How to use the pagination of the JQuery plugin "dataTables" but with the same style as cakephp's pagination?

Tags: cakephp, pagination, datatables, cakephp-2.0, styling

We are using cakephp website.

The only way I could have many data sets with a separate pagination for each dataset on one single page was by suing the great DataTables JQ plugin.
BUT!
I also want the pagination to look like the rest of the website's pagination which is cakephp's(2.0) !

I tried to track what classes cakephp paginator is using from cakephp's cake.generic.css, but when I try to use those classes in oStdClasses of full_numbers method (because that's the pagination type I'm using) they don't apply or things get messed up. I know a little css but I'm not really an expert -- yet! ;) --

Any help, guidance, or ideas would be appreciated...

Update: 
I think what I need help with is understanding how cakephp styles each element of it's pagination and THEN match that with oStdClasses

```
{e.g.
sTable,
sPagePrevEnabled,
sPagePrevDisabled,
sPageNextEnabled,
sPageNextDisabled,sPageButton:,
sPageButtonActive,
sPageButtonStaticDisabled,
sPageFirst,
sPagePrevious,
sPageNext,
sPageLast,
sPaging
}
And I see cakephp using these classes:
/** Paging **/
.paging{..}
.paging .current,
.paging .disabled,
.paging a {..}
.paging > span {..}
.paging > span:hover {..}
.paging .prev {..}
.paging .next {..}
.paging .disabled {..}
.paging .disabled:hover {..}
.paging .current {..}
```

so how to make dataTables take cakephp paging classes...thats what I don't know! ;(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution for this problem long time ago(sorry for the delay in feedback)...and it's like always; much easier than expected!

Instead of modifying the same plugin styles...just inspect elements you want to change their style attributes and redefine same classes again in the same page AFTER invoking datatables plugin.

When two style classes with same name included in a page, the later will be the one that takes effect.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry to say I don't think there's an easy way to do this...

You've done great trying to trace the styles used for cake's pagination, but to match those with the style of DataTables... uff...

What I'd recommend is getting familiar  with [how DataTables styles it's tables](http://www.datatables.net/blog/Creating_beautiful_and_functional_tables_with_DataTables). And then just tweak each element (header, columns, rows, footers) one by one.

With firebug (or similar) style those elements one by one to look like the ones that come with cake. I wouldn't copy-paste every css property and expect it to work (because maybe cake uses `<div>` for a thing, and DataTables a `<span>` and they behave differently). That would be the problem with matching oStdClasses with cake's style.

For example, if DataTables shows the pagination numbers with a table, and cake's pagination with a div, and in the style definition there's something like

```
div.pagination-numbers {/*style*/}
```

it won't apply to the DataTable's table.

It seems like a lot of work to do it "by hand", but in the end you'll get it.